# awk make it less system dependant

Tags: c, bash, awk

If I'm not mistaken, awk parses a number depending on the OS language (eg,`echo "1,2" | awk '{printf("%f\n",$1)}'` would be interpreted as 1 in an english system and as 1.2 in a system where a comma separates the integer from the decimal part).

I don't know if the C printf does this too, so I added the C tag.

I would like to modify the previous command so that it returns the same value (1.2) regardless of the system being used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to the ugliness of *locale*. To fix your problem, first set the locale to the C one.

```
export LC_NUMERIC=C
echo "1,2" | awk '...your code...'
```

To turn off other locale-dependent tomfoolery, you can

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Comment: This is a stupidity in awk. The tomfoolery has to be turned off only because `awk` turns it on. Awk is behaving like an application in this regard, and not as a programming language. It should expose an API to let `awk` programs set up the locale, but otherwise not touch it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `gawk`, you can use the `--use-lc-numeric` option.

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 awk 'BEGIN {printf("%f\n", "1,2")}'
1.000000
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 awk --use-lc-numeric 'BEGIN {printf("%f\n", "1,2")}'
1,200000
```

From the
[GAWK manual](http://gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion)

> The POSIX standard says that awk always uses the period as the decimal
>   point when reading the awk program source code, and for command-line
>   variable assignments (see Other Arguments). However, when interpreting
>   input data, for print and printf output, and for number to string
>   conversion, the local decimal point character is used. Here are some
>   examples indicating the difference in behavior, on a GNU/Linux system:
>
> ```
>  $ gawk 'BEGIN { printf "%g\n", 3.1415927 }'
>  -| 3.14159
>  $ LC_ALL=en_DK gawk 'BEGIN { printf "%g\n", 3.1415927 }'
>  -| 3,14159
>  $ echo 4,321 | gawk '{ print $1 + 1 }'
>  -| 5
>  $ echo 4,321 | LC_ALL=en_DK gawk '{ print $1 + 1 }'
>  -| 5,321
> ```
>
> The ‘en_DK’ locale is for English in Denmark, where the comma acts as
>   the decimal point separator. In the normal "C" locale, gawk treats
>   ‘4,321’ as ‘4’, while in the Danish locale, it's treated as the full
>   number, 4.321.
>
> Some earlier versions of gawk fully complied with this aspect of the
>   standard. However, many users in non-English locales complained about
>   this behavior, since their data used a period as the decimal point, so
>   the default behavior was restored to use a period as the decimal point
>   character. You can use the `--use-lc-numeric` option (see Options) to
>   force gawk to use the locale's decimal point character. (gawk also
>   uses the locale's decimal point character when in POSIX mode, either
>   via `--posix`, or the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable.)

I get similar behavior from `/usr/bin/printf`

```
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 /usr/bin/printf "%f\n" "1,2"
/usr/bin/printf: 1,2: value not completely converted
1,000000
$ LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8 /usr/bin/printf "%f\n" "1.2"
1,200000
```

But without the ability to override it.

If your intent is to do the opposite, that is to take "European" input and
output "US" numbers, you're going to need to use something more robust. Possible
Python or Perl with their locale modules.