# Using tr command inside awk command in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I want to do some arithmetic operations with my values. Here is my log file:

```
SYSAUX                                1050        3,04        55       996         5        95
UNDOTBS1                               420         ,08       395        25        94         6
USERS                                    5         ,01         1         4        19        81
SYSTEM                                 730        2,22         3       727         0       100
EXAMPLE                                346         ,95        36       310        10        90
UNDOTBS2                                50         ,04        38        12        77        23
```

I'm trying to multiply third and fourth columns. In order to do that, i must change "," (comma) to "."(period). I tried to run `tr` command inside `awk` but it gave some errors:

```
cat mylog.log |awk '{mul= $3 * ${4}|tr  "," "\\."; print mul}'


awk: {mul= $3 * ${4}|tr  "," "\\."; print mul}
awk:             ^ syntax error
awk: {mul= $3 * ${4}|tr  "," "\\."; print mul}
awk:                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {mul= $3 * ${4}|tr  "," "\\."; print mul}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                          ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Comment: It can't multiply values that only has a comma. it can multiply 3,2 with 5, but cannot multiply ",4" with 5.

Comment: Can you simply run `tr` before `awk`? `<mylog.log tr ',' '.'  | awk '{print $3*$4}'`

Comment: awk is not shell. Awk has it's very own syntax and it's very own commands, just like C does, and you should not expect to access shell variables, commands, functions, aliases, etc. directly inside an awk script any more than you'd expect to be able to access them directly inside a C program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use the proper locale:

```
LANG=de_DE awk -P '$0 = $3 * $4'
```

Result

```
167,2
31,6
0,01
6,66
34,2
1,52
```

[awk make it less system dependant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10320394/#10322289)

Answer (score 5):

You can run the `tr` transformation before you pass to `awk`:

```
<mylog.log tr ',' '.' | awk '{print $3*$4}'
```

To do this in only `awk`, you could use `sub`:

```
awk '{sub(/,/, "." ,$3); print $3*$4}' mylog.log
```